# Shortest wavelength of sound wave in solids

Tags: frequency, wavelength, crystals, phonons

In the book Thermal Physics by Schroeder, it is mentioned that "sound wave in solids cannot have wavelengths shorter than twice the atomic spacing". I am wondering if this is related to [Nyquist frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem)?

Answer (score 3):

You can think of it as a similar situation. For the Nyquist frequency, you're dealing with a system that's discrete in time. For waves in an (atomic) material, you're dealing with a system that's discrete in space.

That said, I think the wavelength limit is kind of intuitive. How could a shorter wavelength be physically realized? Sure, you can define it mathematically, but the atoms are discreet; there's no matter to move for smaller wavelengths.